# tableTools initializing causing problems with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to combine Bootstrap as well as tableTools with DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var reports_table = $('#reports_table').dataTable({
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath":    "@Url.Content("~/Content/img/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf")"
            }
        });
    });
```

Buttons and plugin works. The problem is that with .DTTT_container, all the Bootstrap classes are gone.

I tried to initialize the search as it is shown from the example :http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/bootstrap.html

It doesnt work. Any help?

Comment: Also it applies the dataTools twice, if copied from the example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Bootstrap classes missing from DTTT_container, here is how I solved it:

Include the script "dataTables.bootstrap.js" AFTER "dataTables.tableTools.js", ie:

```
<!-- Tabletools Datatables Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Datatables Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.6/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The reason dataTools is applied twice, is because you are including "T" in the dom, AND using the new form of initializing in code (`$.fn.dataTable.TableTools()`)

Choose one of the methods and dataTools will not be applied twice.